# How can I change image (png) data and save new one in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, image

Hi I would like to load image on server, then change some pixels values and save new image as png. I came to his stage:

```
  const pixels = require('image-pixels');
  const {data, width, height} = await pixels('http://localhost:8081/image.png');

  console.log(data);

  // Todo change color of pixels
  data[0] = 255;
  data[1] = 255;
  data[2] = 255;

  // Todo: save new image
```

I found I can ´t use Image class in Node so I would like to ask if there is some workaround

output of console.log(data);

```
Uint8Array(400000000) [
  255, 255, 255, 255, 210, 215, 211, 255, 210, 215, 211, 255,
  210, 215, 211, 255, 210, 215, 211, 255, 210, 215, 211, 255,
  210, 215, 211, 255, 210, 215, 211, 255, 210, 215, 211, 255,
  210, 215, 211, 255, 210, 215, 211, 255, 210, 215, 211, 255,
  210, 215, 211, 255, 210, 215, 211, 255, 210, 215, 211, 255,
  210, 215, 211, 255, 210, 215, 211, 255, 210, 215, 211, 255,
  210, 215, 211, 255, 210, 215, 211, 255, 210, 215, 211, 255,
  210, 215, 211, 255, 210, 215, 211, 255, 210, 215, 211, 255,
  210, 215, 211, 255,
  ... 399999900 more items
]
```

Comment: Did you try writing it to a file directly post changing the data: `fs.writeFile('img.png',new Buffer(data))`

Answer (score 0):

This helps me a lot: https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-output

```
var output = require('image-output')

// create chess pattern png from raw pixels data
  output({
    data: data,
    width: width,
    height: height
  }, 'image.png')
```